# How to pass a list from template( html) to view in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How to pass a list from template( html) to view in Django ?
 I need to pass a list from template to a view using url

```
<div class="media-option btn-group shaded-icon">
      {% with uplist=group_list %}
          <button class="btn btn-small" id="button2">
                <a href="{% url 'upload_all_to_group' uplist %}">
                    <i class="icon-plus">Proceed</i>
                </a>
           </button>
       {% endwith %}
</div>
```

Here **uplist** a list, i need to pass it into the view function (upload_all_to_group).

Another problem is , How to specify in urls.py for request matching.

```
url(r'^auth_app/upload_all_to_group/(?P<uplist>(.*))/$',
views.upload_all_to_group, name="upload_all_to_group"),
```

I tried this method. but it's not working.

```
IndexError at /auth_app/auth_app/upload_all_to_group/[['user1',
'RND1', '17-11-2019', 'cc'], ['user3', 'RND2', '08-02-2018', 'ncv'],
['user1', 'group1', '02-02-2018', 'sf'], ['user23', 'RND3',
'16-12-2019', 'der'], ['user2', 'RND3', '25-06-2018', 'ddd']]/
```

This was the error , while pushing this method . How to handle the list in url pattern and view ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is there any unique value (like id) for each item in the list - so that you just pass the IDs?

Comment: why are you not using post request, you can pass anything in the request body?

Comment: could have just make an api to take POST request and send the list within AJAX

Comment: From where `group_list` is coming from?

Comment: Data holded in the list is from a CSV , that is processed from view and listed in template . I need to pass the filtered data from template to view to perform certain action

Answer (score 0):

Your view will receive the list a `string`, not a `list`. You need to convert the `string` representation of the list to a `list`.

In your view,

```
uplist = self.kwargs.get("uplist")
print type(uplist)  # str

uplist_list = eval(uplist)
print type(uplist_list)  # list
```

Use `uplist_list` instead of `uplist` to access your list.